# Disable 'Select All' feature in EXTJS CheckColumn

Tags: extjs

In my jsp, there is a EXTJS component called CheckColumn. Like this:

```
var primaryFundingAccountColumn = new Ext.grid.CheckColumn({
header: '<spring:message javaScriptEscape="true" code="label.account.primary"/>',
dataIndex: 'index',
width: 50,
fixed : true,
menuDisabled : true,
align: 'center',
headerId: 'header1'
});
```

Now when this is added to a grid, on top of the column, there is a checkbox which basically has a function of 'Select All'. On my column, I do not wish to give a Select All Feature. Is there a way to disable it? I tried by removing the `headerId` attribute which I thought would remove the checkbox from the header. But that did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be providing your grid with a [CheckboxSelectionModel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel) config.
In this [CheckboxSelectionModel](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel) config, set `header:'<div>&nbsp;</div>'`  to get rid of the 'select all checkbox' and its functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved me a lot of time. Appreciate your help very much sir.